# MySQL header parsing with Scapy

Tags: python, mysql, parsing, scapy, pcap

I am trying to parse MySQL server-greetings (and client response, later on) packet from a capture file. I am able to see IP and TCP headers, but MySQL header is shown raw by Scapy.

The question is how can i get the salt out of this raw data?

This is what i have in Wireshark (TCP header omitted):

```
MySQL Protocol
Packet Length: 52
Packet Number: 0
Server Greeting
    Protocol: 10
    Version: 5.0.54
    Thread ID: 94
    Salt: >~$4uth,
    Server Capabilities: 0xa22c
    Server Language: utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci (33)
    Server Status: 0x0002
    Extended Server Capabilities: 0x0000
    Authentication Plugin Length: 0
    Unused: 00000000000000000000
    Salt: >612IWZ>fhWX
```

and this is what Scapy gives me:

```
###[ TCP ]###
        sport     = mysql
        dport     = 56162
        seq       = 3442775512
        ack       = 3436755790
        dataofs   = 8
        reserved  = 0
        flags     = PA
        window    = 512
        chksum    = 0x83ab
        urgptr    = 0
        options   = [('NOP', None), ('NOP', None), ('Timestamp', (15785614, 15785614))]
###[ Raw ]###
           load      = b'4\x00\x00\x00\n5.0.54\x00^\x00\x00\x00>~$4uth,\x00,\xa2!\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00>612IWZ>fhWX\x00'
```

As you can see TCP is shown like i could see in Wireshark, but MySQL payload is just raw.

Any suggestion on how to parse it? (Or whats the size of each field in MySQL load? I assume, if I would know the length of each field, I could just simply step that much and read the appropriate data.)

Comment: Doesn't Wireshark give you the offset and size of each identified MySQL field when you click on them (it should highlight the corresponding bytes in the hexadecimal payload at the bottom)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no MySQL protocol support in Scapy, so you have to write your own layers. See the [documentation about adding new layers](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html).